# PHP AdWords API v201809 - How to get city name using LocationCriterionService from GEO_PERFORMANCE_REPORT?

Tags: php, google-ads-api

Instead of pulling a `CRITERIA_PERFORMANCE_REPORT`, I'm pulling a `GEO_PERFORMANCE_REPORT` using this example: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/samples/php/reporting#download-a-criteria-performance-report-with-awql

I'm pulling the `CityCriteriaId` attribute for each result from this API report.

I'm looking to use the `LocationCriterionService` to figure out what the name of the city is based on the IDs that are returned but stuck on the most efficient way to craft this query. Here's what I have so far:

**Dependencies:**

```
namespace Google\AdsApi\Examples\AdWords\v201809\Reporting;
namespace Google\AdsApi\Examples\AdWords\v201809\Targeting;

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// For all the services/methods necessary from the Reporting namespace
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsSession;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsSessionBuilder;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\Query\v201809\ReportQueryBuilder;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\Reporting\v201809\DownloadFormat;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\Reporting\v201809\ReportDefinitionDateRangeType;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\Reporting\v201809\ReportDownloader;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\ReportSettingsBuilder;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201809\cm\DateRange;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201809\cm\ReportDefinitionReportType;
use Google\AdsApi\Common\OAuth2TokenBuilder;

// For all the services/methods necessary for the LocationCriterionService
// and Targeting namespace
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsServices;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201809\cm\LocationCriterionService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201809\cm\Predicate;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201809\cm\PredicateOperator;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201809\cm\Selector;
```

**runExample:** Here's the report code I have (this is all in it's own class):

```
public static function runExample(AdWordsServices $adS, AdWordsSession $session, $reportF)
{
    $query = (new ReportQueryBuilder())
        ->select([
            'CityCriteriaId',
            'Clicks'
        ])
        ->from(ReportDefinitionReportType::GEO_PERFORMANCE_REPORT)
        ->duringDateRange(ReportDefinitionDateRangeType::LAST_7_DAYS)
        ->build();

    $reportDownloader = new ReportDownloader($session);
    $reportSettingsOverride = (new ReportSettingsBuilder())
        ->includeZeroImpressions(false)
        ->build();
    $reportDownloadResult = $reportDownloader->downloadReportWithAwql(
        sprintf('%s', $query),
        $reportF,
        $reportSettingsOverride
    );

    $reportResult = $reportDownloadResult->getAsString();
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($reportResult);
    $data = json_decode(json_encode((array)$xml), TRUE);

    $locationIDs = [];
    $results = $data['table']['row']['@attributes']['city'];
    foreach ($results as $cityID) {
        array_push($locationIDs, $cityID);
    }

    // Here's where I don't know what to do...
    // But any and all code for the LocationCriterionService would be done here

}
```

**Main function:** (taken from the example in the URL above)

```
public static function main()
{
    $oAuth2Credential = (new OAuth2TokenBuilder())->fromFile()->build();

    $session = (new AdWordsSessionBuilder())
        ->fromFile()
        ->withOAuth2Credential($oAuth2Credential)
        ->build();

    self::runExample(new AdWordsServices(), $session, DownloadFormat::XML);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated with regards to what I should place inside of that `foreach` loop that loops through the City IDs from the report result.

**PLEASE NOTE:** I realize that the other way is to store the 100,000 some records (of the .csv Google provides to cross reference cities with their allocated IDs) in a local database and cross reference this way, but this way is preferred.

**EDIT:**

I started getting some progress with some additional code particular for the `LocationCriterionService` yet it yields an error because my parameter for the Predicate variable is wrong (the `soap` dll is required in your `php_info`):

```
$locationCriterionService = $adS->get($session, LocationCriterionService::class);

$selector = new Selector();
$selector->setFields(
    [
        'Id',
        'LocationName',
        'CanonicalName'
    ]
);

$selector->setPredicates(
    [
        new Predicate('locationid', PredicateOperator::EQUALS, $locationIDs)
    ]
);

$locationCriteria = $locationCriterionService->get($selector);

if ($locationCriteria !== null) {
    foreach ($locationCriteria as $locationCriterion) {
        printf(
            "The search term '%s' returned the location '%s' of type '%s' "
            . "with ID %d, and reach %d (%s).\n",
            $locationCriterion->getSearchTerm(),
            $locationCriterion->getLocation()->getLocationName(),
            $locationCriterion->getLocation()->getDisplayType(),
            $locationCriterion->getLocation()->getId()
        );
    }
} else {
    print "No location criteria were found.\n";
}
```

The error is:

> Uncaught Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201809\cm\ApiException:
>   [SelectorError.INVALID_PREDICATE_FIELD_NAME @ selector;
>   trigger:'locationid']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same dilemma. What @slideshowp2 suggests and what you have on you edited answer is the correct approach to solve this. See an original thread from the Google Forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adwords-api/gfbMiTrxcnU.

As stated in there, you should get the real name of the locations from the [`LocationCriterionService`](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201506/LocationCriterionService). You can find an example of how to use this service at https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/samples/php/targeting#get-location-criteria-by-name. This is the one I actually based on in order to get the data I needed, but instead of using the location name I used the location ID as the search criteria.

And here you can see an example of how a location object looks like:

```php
0 => Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201809\cm\LocationCriterion {#7340
  #location: Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201809\cm\Location {#7343
    #locationName: "Fort Lauderdale"
    #displayType: "City"
    #targetingStatus: "ACTIVE"
    #parentLocations: array:4 [
      0 => Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201809\cm\Location {#7338
        #locationName: "Broward County"
        #displayType: "County"
        #targetingStatus: "ACTIVE"
        #parentLocations: null
        #id: 1014969
        #type: null
        #CriterionType: "Location"
        -parameterMap: array:1 [
          "Criterion.Type" => "CriterionType"
        ]
      }
      1 => Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201809\cm\Location {#7339
        #locationName: "Miami-Ft. Lauderdale FL"
        #displayType: "DMA Region"
        #targetingStatus: "ACTIVE"
        #parentLocations: null
        #id: 200528
        #type: null
        #CriterionType: "Location"
        -parameterMap: array:1 [
          "Criterion.Type" => "CriterionType"
        ]
      }
      2 => Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201809\cm\Location {#7337
        #locationName: "Florida"
        #displayType: "State"
        #targetingStatus: "ACTIVE"
        #parentLocations: null
        #id: 21142
        #type: null
        #CriterionType: "Location"
        -parameterMap: array:1 [
          "Criterion.Type" => "CriterionType"
        ]
      }
      3 => Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201809\cm\Location {#7336
        #locationName: "United States"
        #displayType: "Country"
        #targetingStatus: "ACTIVE"
        #parentLocations: null
        #id: 2840
        #type: null
        #CriterionType: "Location"
        -parameterMap: array:1 [
          "Criterion.Type" => "CriterionType"
        ]
      }
    ]
    #id: 1015027
    #type: null
    #CriterionType: "Location"
    -parameterMap: array:1 [
      "Criterion.Type" => "CriterionType"
    ]
  }
  #canonicalName: "Fort Lauderdale,Florida,United States"
  #reach: 1450000
  #locale: null
  #searchTerm: null
  #countryCode: null
}
```

Finally, the error you are getting is because there is not `LocationId` or `locationid` (whatever the way you are using it) in the `Location` object. You should use `Id` instead. See the documentation for the `Location` object at https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201809/LocationCriterionService.Location#id.

Btw, the API version I used is the same as yours: `v201809`.

Answer (score 2):

I use `Node.js` write my google adwords application.

Google adwords API: `v201809`.

Here is my case:

I get `xml` data of `GEO_PERFORMANCE_REPORT` like this:

```
<row campaignID='1733539359' campaign='Campaign Name3.0-119-1552463540147' impressions='1' countryTerritory='2818' city='1005392'/>
<row campaignID='1733539359' campaign='Campaign Name3.0-119-1552463540147' impressions='4' countryTerritory='2716' city='1028774'/>
```

As you can see, there are two fields named: `countryTerritory` and `city`.

They are [countrycriteriaid](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/geo-performance-report#countrycriteriaid) and [citycriteriaid](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/geo-performance-report#citycriteriaid)

Now, I want to get the country name and city name. It can be done using [LocationCriterionService](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201809/LocationCriterionService)

Here is my code snippet for `selector`:

```
 const criterionIds = [2818, 2716, 1005392, 1028774];

 const selector = new AdWords.Selector.model({
      fields: ['CanonicalName', 'Reach'],
      predicates: [ {
        field: 'Id',
        operator: 'IN',
        values: criterionIds
      }],
      ordering: []
    })
```

And I get the response:

```
{
    "entries": [
        {
            "location": {
                "id": "2716",
                "Criterion.Type": "Location",
                "locationName": "Zimbabwe",
                "displayType": "Country",
                "targetingStatus": "ACTIVE"
            },
            "canonicalName": "Zimbabwe",
            "reach": "736000"
        },
        {
            "location": {
                "id": "2818",
                "Criterion.Type": "Location",
                "locationName": "Egypt",
                "displayType": "Country",
                "targetingStatus": "ACTIVE"
            },
            "canonicalName": "Egypt",
            "reach": "20300000"
        },
        {
            "location": {
                "id": "1005392",
                "Criterion.Type": "Location",
                "locationName": "Damietta",
                "displayType": "City",
                "targetingStatus": "ACTIVE",
                "parentLocations": [
                    {
                        "id": "21479",
                        "Criterion.Type": "Location",
                        "locationName": "Damietta Governorate",
                        "displayType": "Governorate",
                        "targetingStatus": "ACTIVE"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "2818",
                        "Criterion.Type": "Location",
                        "locationName": "Egypt",
                        "displayType": "Country",
                        "targetingStatus": "ACTIVE"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "canonicalName": "Damietta,Damietta Governorate,Egypt",
            "reach": "593000"
        },
        {
            "location": {
                "id": "1028774",
                "Criterion.Type": "Location",
                "locationName": "Harare",
                "displayType": "City",
                "targetingStatus": "ACTIVE",
                "parentLocations": [
                    {
                        "id": "9070024",
                        "Criterion.Type": "Location",
                        "locationName": "Harare Province",
                        "displayType": "Province",
                        "targetingStatus": "ACTIVE"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "2716",
                        "Criterion.Type": "Location",
                        "locationName": "Zimbabwe",
                        "displayType": "Country",
                        "targetingStatus": "ACTIVE"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "canonicalName": "Harare,Harare Province,Zimbabwe",
            "reach": "593000"
        }
    ]
}
```

Hope it can help.